# Web Scraping: How to click button in selenium without opening webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, click

I am using selenium scraping code in Windows VPS, Now code open chrome browser in order to click button, but I need to use the code in Ubuntu VPS.
As you know Ubuntu VPS don't provide any UI. So I need to click button in selenium without opening webdriver - chrome browser.

I tested --headless option but not works.

Follow my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options = chrome_options)
link = "site url"
driver.get(link)
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")
button.click()
print("Clicked Accept_BTN")
```

Comment: I think the headless work Try retrieving some text because as you can't see what it's doing

Comment: _tested --headless option but not works_: What makes you feel your test doesn't work? Are you seeing any error?

Comment: I meant I can't click button in webdriver using --headless option, there is any way to solve it using --headless option in Ubuntu OS?

Comment: @Victor, `button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")` is this the correct locator? Please recheck. The DOM is not posted in query, but by looking at it, prima facie, it looks more like a tag name than css selector. If you have a device where you can check the headed version, please check there to rule out such thing; or post the DOM here to replicate the issue. Without DOM or website link, anyone can suggest, but it would not be backed by testing it.